# Probability of an equation being less than/greater than a certain value

Tags: probability

I'm studying probability and the form of a problem that we are working on is:

$x^2 + y^2 < n/k$, the question being what is the probability that the equation is less than (or greater than) the $n/k$, given intervals for $x$ and $y$ such as 
$0 < x <1$, $-1 < y < 1$ and $n$ and $k$ are just two random values.

$n$ and $y$ are just chosen values. Distribution is not specified

A concrete example:

What is the probability that $x^2 + (1-y)^2 < 1/9$

I had started using joint density functions and integrating with respect to $x$ and $y$ using the intervals as the support for the integration limits. Doing that gets me $8/9$ but I'm not certain if that is indicative of $8/9$ < $1/9$, so the probability is just $0$ or what??? :) Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by random values? What is the distribution of $x, y, n,k$, and are they chosen independently? Also, in the example, you specified an $n$ and a $k$. So are they fixed? Because then they are not random. Be more specific.

Comment: You need to calculate the circles with radius less than $\frac{1}{3}$ centered at $(0,1)$ in the given interval.

Comment: "Distribution is not specified" Which is BAD but probably means one is assuming uniform distributions. (Odd to see an answer avoiding this crucial point, that you are explicitely asking about, being accepted after 5 minutes.)

Comment: @Did, How is one going to solve this without specified distribution. Uniform distribution is the way to go in such cases.

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Indeed one needs a distribution to be specified, and this is not the case here, which makes this exercise a badly composed and misleading one, most probably by sheer laziness of the person who wrote it. "Uniform distribution is the way to go in such cases." Certainly not by hiding the problem under the rug, as your answer does.

Comment: @Did, Should I deleted the answer then?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Your problem (and the OP's), not mine. Another option would be to modify your answer, so that it really addresses the question, its flaws included (and apparently, this is just what you did, in a way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As question specifies no distribution, I am assuming uniform
>   distribution.As **[@Did](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/6179/did)** pointed out this is a badly composed problem, but
>   since this answer solves a part of the problem. I will keep this
>   intact.

You are looking at equation of an circle with restricted domain, This can be easily plotted as,

[image]

The area of the points in the domain which satisfy the condition $$x^2+(1-y)^2\lt\frac{1}{9}$$ is

$$\frac{1}{4}\pi\frac{1}{3^2}=\frac{\pi}{36}$$

The area of the domain is $2\cdot1=2$.

Assuming uniform distribution, the required probability is the ratio of these areas, that is, $$\frac{\frac{\pi}{36}}{2}=\frac{\pi}{72}$$